# how to save image from a dive and save it into a server directory with php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image-uploading

i want to say an image from a div and i want to save it ito a server directory with ajax call (without page refresh). LIke the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

   <body>
 <div class="test">
<img src="one.jpg" />
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now i want to save it into a server folder with ajax call but i don't have any idea how i can do this, kindly guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't know the solution kindly give up vote so may someone else can answer. Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? `one.jpg` is stored already on the server, why do you want to upload it? You could upload it to another server (for example) with a php curl request - no ajax is required.